# Add css with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to add a background image to an element, but it's not working.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(function(){
            $('.header').css('background-image','url(<?php echo header_image(); ?>)');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The site is realwealthaccess.com

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Most likely, the path you're trying to set is invalid. Add an `alert('<?php echo header_image(); ?>');` to the script to see what it's returning. I'd suggest adding the code for you `header_image` to your question, if possible.

Comment: It's valid, if you inspect it, you'll see it's a valid path.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, you probably need to put the url in quotes because you have non-URL-safe characters:

```
$('.header').css('background-image','url("<?php echo header_image(); ?>")');
//                                       ^        here and here        ^
```

Comment: Quotes are optional in url rule.

Comment: I'm saying that in OP's case it's `'url(http://realwealthaccess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cropped-top_banner20.jpg)'` and yes it will work. Just try it, OP provided a link. If the url is valid resource it doesn't need quotes.

Comment: @dfsq You are right about the noConflict issue, but not about the quotes being optional because they are needed for irregular URLs.

Comment: @Shomz Maybe for irregular. I just know that in most cases you can just omit them. Trying to find a spec now, to find out.

Comment: @Robert, combine my answer with dfsq's answer and it will work, make sure you replace all `$` calls with `jQuery` (or stop using noConflict if you don't need it).

Comment: @dfsq, I'm also trying to find something official, although I'm 100% sure I had to use quotes a few times when dealing with irregular URLs. +1 for your answer anyway.

Comment: @Shomz See this is what I found on W3C http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri

Comment: @dfsq Good find! I tried finding an image with spaces so I can make a jsfiddle test, but couldn't find any within 5 minutes, so I gave up. :) But yeah, the w3c specs are iffy as usual, they didn't say why the quotes exist in the first place. I'll try to make those tests now.

Comment: @Shomz Yes, interesting. Let me know if you can replicate a problem.

Comment: @Shomz I see. Yes it actually makes sense, because spec says that URI may be "followed by optional white space". So in case of spaces it's considered end of URL, but obviously it's not. So yes, in this case quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in no conflict mode you must use `jQuery` instead of `$`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.header').css('background-image','url(<?php echo header_image(); ?>)');
});
```

Comment: Did you also change `$(function(){` to `jQuery(function() { ... })`?

Comment: And also try fixing errors on the page, maybe they prevent it from working properly.

Comment: Strange. For some reason `jQuery(function() { ... })` is not executed. I think you should fix `overlay` error first. Probably it interferes with further loading.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this (to make it like a normal CSS background-image declaration):

```
      var imageUrl ="<?php echo $impage_path ?>"
     $('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Alternatively to what the others are correctly suggesting, I find it easier usually to toggle CSS classes, instead of individual CSS settings (especially background image URLs). For example:

```
// in CSS 
.bg1 
{
  background-image: none;
}

.bg2 
{
  background-image: url(/another/image/url/there.jpg);
}

// in JS
// based on value of imageUrl, determine what class to remove and what class to add.
$('myOjbect').removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');
```

Comment: As a replacement for this `).removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');` you can use `.toggleClass('bg1 bg2')`

Comment: sure this is also a way  @RajaprabhuAravindasamy